# Create a list of paired string values in PowerShell

Tags: list, powershell, hashtable

For a project I am doing, I need to check and see if a pair of strings are present in a line from a file.

I have tried to use a hash table like this:

```
$makes = 'Ferrari', 'Ford', 'VW', 'Peugeot', 'Subaru'
$models = 'Enzo', 'Focus', 'Golf', '206', 'Impreza'

$table = @{}

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $makes.Length; $i++)
{
    $table.Add($makes[$i], $models[$i])
}
```

This works well until I try to insert a duplicate make. I quickly found out that hash tables do not accept duplicates.

So is there a way of creating a double list of strings in PowerShell? It is very easy to do in C# , but i have found no way of achieving it in PowerShell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With minimal changes to your code and logic:

```
$makes = 'Ferrari', 'Ford', 'VW', 'Peugeot', 'Subaru'
$models = 'Enzo', 'Focus', 'Golf', '206', 'Impreza'

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $makes.Length; $i++){
    [array]$cars += New-Object psobject -Property @{
        make  = $makes[$i]
        model = $models[$i]

    }
}
```

This uses custom `psobject`, cast to an array so that `+=` is allowed.

Comment: Thanks for that. Works good! I never knew you could modify arrays like that.

Answer (score 11):

You can use a `PSCustomObject` and just populate the list directly:

```
$cars = @(
    [pscustomobject]@{make = "Ferrari"; model="Enzo"}
    [pscustomobject]@{make = "Ford"; model="Focus"}
    [pscustomobject]@{make = "Peugeot"; model="206"}
    [pscustomobject]@{make = "Subaru"; model="Imprezza"}
)
```

Comment: How would this be different if I remove the "[pscustomobject]" parts?  It works apparently the same under PS5. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way that avoids array concatenation (similar to Python "list comprehension" syntax):

```
$makes = 'Ferrari', 'Ford', 'VW', 'Peugeot', 'Subaru'
$models = 'Enzo', 'Focus', 'Golf', '206', 'Impreza'

$cars = 0..$makes.Length | ForEach-Object {
  [PSCustomObject] @{
    Make  = $makes[$_]
    Model = $models[$_]
  }
}
```

Comment: From what you have posted it is in no way clear what the "O.", means. For me as a newbie PowerShell user it looks like it is some kind of shorthand syntax sugar. Aka shortening something which would have otherwise been clear. For those other newbies like me, is is the Range Opperator, and it is explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-5.1#range-operator-

Answer (score 2):

Note: The question as asked - creating a *list* of value pairs, *irrespective of duplicates* - is most efficiently answered by [Bill Stewart's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44163387/45375).
This answer focuses on a hashtable-based solution that collects all models for a given make in a single entry and allows efficient lookup of models by make.

---

You can still **use a hashtable** - with its convenient, key-based lookups - if you **store all models associated with a given make as an *array* in each make's - by definition one and only - entry**:

```powershell
# Note the duplicate 'VW' entry at the end.
$makes = 'Ferrari', 'Ford', 'VW', 'Peugeot', 'Subaru', 'VW'
# Corresponding models.
$models = 'Enzo', 'Focus', 'Golf', '206', 'Impreza', 'Polo'

$table = [ordered] @{}; $i=0  # [ordered] (PSv3+) preserves the order of the keys
foreach($make in $makes) {
  # Add the model at hand to the make's array of models.
  # The entry is created on demand as an array, due to [array]
  # (which creates an [object[]] array),
  # and for additional models the array is appended to.
  # You could also use [string[]], specifically.
  [array] $table[$make] += $models[$i++]
}

# Output the resulting hashtable
$table
```

This yields:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                               
----                           -----                                                                                                                                               
Ferrari                        {Enzo}                                                                                                                                              
Ford                           {Focus}                                                                                                                                             
VW                             {Golf, Polo}                                                                                                                                        
Peugeot                        {206}                                                                                                                                               
Subaru                         {Impreza}
```

Note how `VW`'s value has *2* entries (`{...}` indicates that a value is an array).

To get a given make's model(s) later, simply use:

```
$vwModels = $table['VW']
```

To check if a given make / model pair is already contained in the table:

```
$table[$make] -contains $model
```